# Spring integration router configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am struggling to find examples using the @Router annotation. If I am understanding the javadocs correctly:

```
@Service
public class AgentServiceImpl implements AgentService {

    @Override
    @Router(inputChannel = "agentLogin", defaultOutputChannel = "agentServiceResponse")
    public AgentLoginResponse login(AgentLoginRequest request) {

    }
}
```

In the xml examples with the router there was a service-activator, which is where I am getting hung up on trying to figure out how it will fit in.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do that wrong way. See `@Router` JavaDocs:

```
* Indicates that a method is capable of resolving to a channel or channel name
* based on a message, message header(s), or both.
```

So, your `login` method for the target `router` component must return a `channel name` or entire `MessageChannel` object.

Comment: Would @Router then be used with one's own logic on where the message should be sent, instead of using 1 of spring integrations routers like the payload or expression router?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. `@Router` exactly does the same as `<router>`. As we know the last one is based on the mapping logic from some value from underlying processor (expression or POJO). Since we mark a method with `@Router` there is may be no reason to have `mapping`, because we always can return a channel name from that method. From other side this annotation has additional option - `channelMappings()`. Again: see JavaDocs.